# Let's Ascend the Devils Tower

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| The speed of a jet | ---- |
| **Huge like an ocean or galaxy** | ---- |
| In the end.... | ---- |
| **Some set of items** | ---- |
| It's mostly a feminine name | ---- |
| Something like emitting a coherent light | ---- |
| **N & n each has its own** | ---- |
| **Oliver Phelps in Harry Potter series** | ---- |
| **This is kind of a price estimate** | ---- |
| Heavy weapon | ---- |
| Eh, money money money | ---- |
| **Lots of babies can have it often** | ---- |
| Pelting across the road | ---- |
| I was once a President | ---- |
| **Not available** | ---- |
| Go conceal under the ground | ---- |

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This puzzle is:

> A *word ladder* (hence the use of 'ascend' in the title and the mention of [the Devils Tower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Ladder_(Devils_Tower_National_Monument)), a landmark accessible by ladder), where the answer to each rung can be found by changing a single letter in the previous entry. It can be resolved as follows:
>
>  **FAST** = The speed of a jet
>  **[V]AST** = Huge like an ocean or galaxy
>  **[L]AST** = In the end....
>  **L[I]ST** = Some set of items
>  **LIS[E]** = It's mostly a feminine name *(e.g. [Lise Meitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lise_Meitner))*
>  **L[A]SE** = Something like emitting a coherent light
>  **[C]ASE** = N & n each has its own *(i.e. upper and lower case)*
>  **CAS[T]** = Oliver Phelps in Harry Potter series *(since Oliver Phelps was part of the movie's **cast**, playing Fred Weasley)*
>  **C[O]ST** = This is kind of a price estimate
>  **COS[H]** = Heavy weapon
>  **C[A]SH** = Eh, money money money
>  **[R]ASH** = Lots of babies can have it often
>  **R[U]SH** = Pelting across the road
>  **[B]USH** = I was once a President
>  **BUS[Y]** = Not available
>  **BU[R]Y** = Go conceal under the ground

If we look at the rows emphasised in bold text...

> ...and see what letters were added in for these steps, we can spell out the word **VICTORY**, which is likely the intended final answer to be derived from the puzzle:
>
>  [V]AST ... L[I]ST ... [C]ASE CAS[T] C[O]ST ... [R]ASH ... BUS[Y]

There's a red herring in the puzzle also:

> The initial letters of the clues spell "THIS IS NOT HELPING".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Ladder_(Devils_Tower_National_Monument) Great job as always!! :)